# SQLite: How to fetch the ORDER index of COUNT

Tags: sql, sqlite, count, query-optimization

I have an SQLite database that contains a list of user messages in a group.
And I want to get a user's "rank" by counting the number of messages they had sent.

Currently I'm doing this

```sql
SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) as count 
FROM message
group by user_id
ORDER BY count DESC
```

It'd return something like this:

| - | user_id | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2072040132 | 61877 |
| 2 | 1609505732 | 40514 |
| 3 | 1543287045 | 34735 |
| 4 | 203349203 | 30570 |
| 5 | 842634673 | 29651 |
| 6 | 1702633101 | 29185 |
| 7 | 1978947042 | 27728 |
| 8 | 1929648593 | 27025 |
| 9 | 1069841429 | 17944 |
| 10 | 1437208364 | 17344 |
| 11 | ... | ... |

Like user `1609505732` is top 2, and `1702633101` is top 6.

But my database has more than 2 million rows, and this is too slow having to fetch all of the list.
I was wondering if there are any way that I can fetch only the order of it.

Like this:

| - | user_id | order | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1702633101 | 6 | 61877 |

And the user with id=`1702633101` is top 6. That'd be a lot faster.

Thanks for spending time on my question, I can't seem to find the answer anywhere on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To improve query speed, I'd consider physicalising the aggregate view, example below:

```
CREATE Table as tbl_aggregate()
Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
, user_id NVARCHAR
, count INT;



INSERT INTO tbl_aggregate 
SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) as count 
FROM message
group by user_id
ORDER BY count DESC;

Select * from tbl_aggregate
Where Id = 6

Select top 10 * from tbl_aggregate
```

Comment: What black magic is this? The query time went from 150ms to 73ms, thank you so much!